# Include the current date in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need the current date in a field within a project aggregation stage like this:

```
$project:{
   todays_date: ''
}
```

I need some checks on basis of that below, 
I tried many things but they are not allowing me to add like this:

```
$project:{
  todays_date: Date(), 
}
```

but the date is from 1970.

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, you can use the new aggregation variable [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) which provides the current datetime:

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $project: { todays_date: "$$NOW" } })
// { todays_date: ISODate("2019-07-21T09:05:46.123Z") }
```

Comment: actually i have mongo3.6, and i need to run this on different client systems where mongo version could be 3.6, 3.2 or 4 .